# Purpose of an Iodine Flask

Tags: equipment

Is there any specific reason why Iodine Flasks are used instead of Erlenmeyer Flasks when doing Iodine Determination tests?

Iodine Flasks are quite expensive when compared to Erlenmeyer Flasks.

Does the funnel-shaped top form serve a specific function?

Answer (score 6):

[image: Iodine flask][image: Erlenmeyer flasks]

Iodine flasks differ from normal conical (Erlenmeyer) flasks in three main ways:

- The ground glass joint.
- The modified stopper.
- The funnel shaped top.

Iodine itself, and iodine related molecules produced during the analysis are, to a certain extent, volatile (you can see this if you just put a bead of iodine in a sealed vial and watch the vial fill with vapour). The ground glass joint of the iodine flask prevents these vapours from escaping, improving the accuracy of your analysis.

As for the funnel, its simply there to help get your stuff into the flask in the first place, preventing loss through spillage and preventing the need for a separate glass funnel. Anything that ends up on the tapered neck is simply rinsed directly into the flask.

Answer (score 2):

The funnel-shaped top form serves a specific function. In the standardization of sodium thiosulfate with potassium iodate for example, there is a waiting time for liberation of iodine. That is when the analyst fills the tapered neck with purified water to "seal" the flask and prevent escape of iodine. When the lid is removed for the titration step, let the purified water go through the flask and act as a rinse.